# Why is this the answer (Online Test)?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

A man gave one son 10 cents and another son was given 15 cents. What time is it?

This was asked on an online test, and it has been bothering me why the answer is the answer.

I think it was either 3:15 or 3:45 sorry I cannot remember which but I guessed and being that I got a 100% on the test it was right.

Comment: Are you certain you have the right permissions to post this question here, since it is not your own? If you are allowed to post it you should also add the source to give credit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer should be:

> 1:45, which isn't either of the answers that you put (but I'm pretty sure it's right.)

Reasoning:

> The man gave a total of 25 cents to two people. 25 cents is a quarter, so the time is *a quarter to two*, or 1:45.

Comment: That was one of the answers, I do not really trust that the scoring was correct, however when you try to take the test again, it will only show you your score and I didn't put in the effort to open an incognito, but it was bothering me how (3:15 or 3:45) was correct it made no sense. Thank You